# MMQGIS Plugin returns 0 geocoded in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, geocoding, mmqgis

I have a geocoding problem using the MMQGIS Plugin to perform geocoding analysis

So far, I successfully geocoded about 130.000 enterprises and once at suddenly, MMQGIS Plugin just started to return 0 found enterprises. I am performing exactly the same procedure as I did for the previous 130.000 enterprises. In fact, I tried to test again exactly the same files that previously were successfully geocoded (exactly the same file) and now, those files are also returned with 0 results.

I was performing analysis via Google, using an API key.

I tried to research a problem and I have noticed people previously also faced this problem, however, any of possible solutions could not help me.

[image]

Comment: Google is blocking your IP address.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help, this might be a case. But when I try the analysis via Open Street Map, I also got 0 gecoded results. Prior when I tried to preform the analysis with OSM, I got 7 out of 10 geocoded enterprises with the same file.

Comment: Could it be that OSM also doesn't work because Google is blocking my IP address, or this should not be related? I did a lot of geocoding (about 130,000 enterprises in the last two days), so maybe I exceed some limits and that's why I am blocked. Is there a way to sort out this and get unblocked? Thank you again.